# Database setup for Cartalyst/Sentinel

Tags: php, authentication, sentinel

https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#sentinel-authenticate

I've followed the basic installation in the Sentinel documentation for Native usage as I don't have Laravel installed, I have installed all the packages via Composer and I'd like to start doodling with Sentinel to test it before using it into production. My problem is I don't know how to setup MySQL/MariaDB for tables Sentinel will use, in fact I got an Exception like this

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found
```

Some other packages give the basic SQL file to import, but I don't know how to deal with database setup for Sentinel, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a schema folder here: https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/tree/2.0/schema

You can find a mysql.sql (or mysql5.6+.sql) script to create your tables.